# Storing an Array of Objects in Redux-Toolkit - Array is logging empty but it isn't

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am using Redux-Toolkit on React.

I am trying to store an array of objects in my redux store that will be a list of chat messages.

Here is my clientSlice.js (where my actions are created)

```
 export const clientSlice = createSlice({
        name: 'client',
        initialState: {
            messages: []
        },

        reducers: {
           //Add message to list of messages
           setAddMessage: (state, action) => {
               state.messages.push(action.payload);
           }
        },
    });
```

I am able to add objects to the array using useDispatch(setAddMessage(message))

In my messages.js I am able to map the messages onto my HTML like so:

```
const messages = useSelector(selectMessages);

{messages ? (
  [...Object.values(messages)]
  .sort((a, b) => a.time - b.time).map((message) => (
    <div
    key={message.id}
    className="message-container"
    >
    <span className="message-user">{message.user}</span>
    <span className="message-content">{message.value}</span>
    <span className="message-date">{new Date(message.time).toLocaleTimeString()}</span>
    </div>          
  ))
   ) : (<div></div>)}
```

Works fine... my messages show up on the front end.

**However, my issue arises when I try and console.log(messages) from my Messages.js file.**
I get the response:

```
Array []
​
length: 0
​
<prototype>: Array []
```

Even though my messages are continuing to appear from mapping "messages"... it logs length 0.

Also, If I try to do something like

```
console.log(messages[1])
-undefined
```

What am I missing here guys?

Answer (score 1):

Hi you should change the selector tag in your messages.js to this

```js
 const count = useSelector((state) => state.name)
```

Where name is the name of reducer of your redux config